# How to add a loop in calculator program

Tags: ruby

I created a calculator in ruby. I am wondering how to put this in a loop so I don't have to run it constantly. I am new to programming so please understand I am I just trying to learn. I would appreciate any help provided.

```
puts "Hello, My name is Calvin The Calculator and I am a calculator that can do basic functions such as Adding, Subtracting, Multiplying and Dividing"
puts "Press a and enter to enable my services"

enable = gets.chomp
if enable == "a"
  puts "Choose which operation you want to do. + for adding, - for subtraction, * for multiplication and / for division"
else
  "Puts Im Waiting..."
end

which_operation = gets.chomp
if which_operation == "+"
  puts "What is the first number you want to add"
  adding_first_number = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "What is the second number you want to add to #{adding_first_number}"
  adding_second_number = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "#{adding_first_number} + #{adding_second_number} is #{adding_first_number + adding_second_number}" 
else

end

if which_operation == "-"
  puts "What is the first number you want to subtract"
  subtracting_first_number = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "What is the number you want to subtract from #{subtracting_first_number}"
  subtracting_second_number = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "#{subtracting_first_number} -  #{subtracting_second_number} is #{subtracting_first_number - subtracting_second_number}"
else

end

if which_operation == "*"
  puts "What is the first number you want to multiple"
  multiplying_first_number = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "What is the number you want to multiple #{multiplying_first_number} by"
  multiplying_second_number = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "#{multiplying_first_number} * by #{multiplying_second_number} is #{multiplying_first_number * multiplying_second_number}"
else

end

if which_operation == "/"
  puts "What is the first number to your divison question?"
  dividing_first_number = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "What is the divisor?"
  dividing_second_number = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "#{dividing_first_number} divided by #{dividing_second_number} is #{dividing_first_number / dividing_second_number}"
else

end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add loop on ruby calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921638/how-to-add-loop-on-ruby-calculator)

Answer (score 0):

For example:
`until (which_operation = gets.chomp).empty?
    if which_operation == "+"
      ...
    end
    if which_operation == "-"
      ...
    end
    if which_operation == "*"
      ...
    end
    if which_operation == "/"
      ...
    end
 end`
This loop will work until you press Enter without entering any text before it.
P.S.: Better use **case** operator instead of multiple **if**.
P.P.S.: All your code, after loop addition and without **case** operator, will be:

```
puts "Hello, My name is Calvin The Calculator and I am a calculator that can do basic functions such as Adding, Subtracting, Multiplying and Dividing"
puts "Press a and enter to enable my services"

until gets.chomp == "a"
  puts "I'm Waiting..."
end
puts "Choose which operation you want to do. + for adding, - for subtraction, * for multiplication and / for division"

until (which_operation = gets.chomp).empty?
  if which_operation == "+"
    puts "What is the first number you want to add"
    adding_first_number = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "What is the second number you want to add to #{adding_first_number}"
    adding_second_number = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "#{adding_first_number} + #{adding_second_number} is #{adding_first_number + adding_second_number}"
  elsif which_operation == "-"
    puts "What is the first number you want to subtract"
    subtracting_first_number = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "What is the number you want to subtract from #{subtracting_first_number}"
    subtracting_second_number = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "#{subtracting_first_number} -  #{subtracting_second_number} is #{subtracting_first_number - subtracting_second_number}"
  elsif which_operation == "*"
    puts "What is the first number you want to multiple"
    multiplying_first_number = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "What is the number you want to multiple #{multiplying_first_number} by"
    multiplying_second_number = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "#{multiplying_first_number} * by #{multiplying_second_number} is #{multiplying_first_number * multiplying_second_number}"
  elsif which_operation == "/"
    puts "What is the first number to your divison question?"
    dividing_first_number = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "What is the divisor?"
    dividing_second_number = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "#{dividing_first_number} divided by #{dividing_second_number} is #{dividing_first_number / dividing_second_number}"
  end
  puts "\nLet's try again: "
end
```

Comment: Where would I put that in the program?

Comment: Around all checking:
`until (which_operation = gets.chomp).empty?
   if which_operation == "+"
   ...
   if which_operation == "-"
   ...
   if which_operation == "*"
   ...
   if which_operation == "/"
   ...
 end`

Comment: Everywhere I would put it, it would just say syntax error. Can you write the whole code out and put the edit you said would work? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't continue the program it just stops asking questions. Maybe if you write every line of code down than it will work